# jqueryMobile with Php application conver to apk Apps

Tags: php, android, jquery, wordpress, apk

I have made Jquery mobile for wordpress site. Now I'm looking APK for Android open market. Can anyone have help me a little more details Jquery mobile and PHP to APK apps.

I'm totally new here.

Thank you

### Here is **Jquery mobile with PHP Wordpress** index code

```
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-filter="true" data-counttheme="e">
    <?php if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <h2> 
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-transition="slidedown"><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
        </h2>
        <article> <?php echo the_excerpt(); ?> </article>

    </li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </ul>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Well, PHP is a server side language, you can not run a php jQuery site in android, you can make an APK file with a webview, whick opens a web site in remote server, but you can not run php website in a android application in your case APK.